# Convert Data in postman api using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postman

how do I convert the data as shown below (ignore the values)

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: If you use postman you can paste raw json content in `body` of a new request, set it as `raw` and of type `json` and press `beautify` button on the right of window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json_encode()` has a flag `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Or you can use JSON beautifier websites like [this](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer)